# I have two references frames with three vectors in each - how do I find the rotation matrix between them?

Tags: rotations

I have a problem involving reference frames that I was hoping for help with.

I have two references frames, A and B with a common origin. I have three vectors $f$,$g$,$h$ in each references frame, i.e. I have $f_{xA}, f_{yA}, f_{zA}$ and $f_{xB} ... f_{zB}$, and similarly for $g$ and $h$. The components of the vectors can be of any value and are not generally orthogonal to each other although I have some say in choosing these vectors in reference frame A. The problem I have is in getting from reference frame B to A - I believe that a unique rotation should exist but cannot find any references on how to find it.

Thanks for your help,
Pete

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An easily-to-implement solution is to formulate a linear equation system for the coefficients of $\mathbf{R}_{ab}$ (solvable in MatLab, Python, ...), although these nine coefficients are not independent of each other (constraints of SO3-group), anyway it works fairly well
\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
f_{ax}& f_{ay} & f_{az} & 0 & 0 &0  & 0 & 0 &0 \\
0 & 0 &0 & f_{ax}& f_{ay} & f_{az} & 0 & 0 &0 \\
0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 0 &0 & f_{ax}& f_{ay} & f_{az}\\
g_{ax}& g_{ay} & g_{az} & 0 & 0 &0  & 0 & 0 &0 \\
0 & 0 &0 & g_{ax}& g_{ay} & g_{az} & 0 & 0 &0 \\
0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 0 &0 & g_{ax}& g_{ay} & g_{az}\\
h_{ax}& h_{ay} & h_{az} & 0 & 0 &0  & 0 & 0 &0 \\
0 & 0 &0 & h_{ax}& h_{ay} & h_{az} & 0 & 0 &0 \\
0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 0 &0 & h_{ax}& h_{ay} & h_{az}
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
R_{xx}\\ R_{xy}\\ R_{xz}\\ R_{yx}\\ R_{yy}\\ R_{yz}\\ R_{zx}\\ R_{zy}\\ R_{zz}
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
f_{bx}\\ f_{by}\\ f_{bz}\\ 
g_{bx}\\ g_{by}\\ g_{bz}\\ 
h_{bx}\\ h_{by}\\ h_{bz}
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}
Alternatively, you may choose parametrizations with less parameters, and consequently solve less, but nonlinear equations (choose the convenient ones in the problem at hand). For example with Euler-parameters ($a$, $b$, $c$ $d$), you would express all components of $\mathbf{R}(a,b,c,d)$ in dependency on four parameters: $R_{xx}=a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2$, $\ $ $R_{xy}=2(bc-ad)$, $\ $ $\dots$

If you were free to choose orthonormal basis vectors in one of the two systems (A or B), then you would directly get the rows in one direction (other direction is the transpose $\mathbf{R}_{ab}^\text{T} = \mathbf{R}_{ba}$, since rotation matrices $\mathbf{R}$ are orthogonal).

Comment: This is a bunch of hints at the very best but far from being an answer to OP's question.

Comment: Hey Dominik, thanks for the very helpful answer - coded up your solution in python and it was exactly what I needed.

Comment: By the way ``scipy.spatial.transform`` may provide many operations you need.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf{f}, \mathbf{g}, \mathbf{h}$ be the three vectors expressed using the standard basis, then

$[\mathbf{f},\mathbf{g},\mathbf{h}] = R_A [ \mathbf{f}_A,\mathbf{g}_A,\mathbf{h}_A ]= R_B [\mathbf{f}_B,\mathbf{g}_B,\mathbf{h}_B ] $

Therefore,

$R_A = R_B [\mathbf{f}_B,\mathbf{g}_B,\mathbf{h}_B ][ \mathbf{f}_A,\mathbf{g}_A,\mathbf{h}_A ]^{-1} $

And this is how you get from frame $B$ to frame $A$.